# SQL to Entity Framework Count Group-By

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, count, group-by

I need to translate this `SQL` statement to a `Linq-Entity` query...

```
SELECT name, count(name) FROM people
GROUP by name
```

Comment: if anyone want to `group by + join rows data`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558509/concatenate-and-group-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Answer (score 233, accepted):

**Query syntax**

```
var query = from p in context.People
            group p by p.name into g
            select new
            {
              name = g.Key,
              count = g.Count()
            };
```

**Method syntax**

```
var query = context.People
                   .GroupBy(p => p.name)
                   .Select(g => new { name = g.Key, count = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 25):

#### Edit: EF Core 2.1 finally supports [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation)

But always look out in the console / log for messages. If you see a notification that your query could not be converted to SQL and will be evaluated locally then you may need to rewrite it.

---

**Entity Framework 7** (now renamed to **Entity Framework Core 1.0 / 2.0**) does not yet support `GroupBy()` for translation to `GROUP BY` in generated SQL (even in the final 1.0 release it won't). Any grouping logic will run on the client side, which could cause a lot of data to be loaded.

Eventually code written like this will automagically start using GROUP BY, but for now you need to be very cautious if loading your whole un-grouped dataset into memory will cause performance issues.

For scenarios where this is a deal-breaker you will have to write the SQL by hand and execute it through EF.

If in doubt fire up Sql Profiler and see what is generated - which you should probably be doing anyway.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-rc2

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Also no grouping in 1.1

Comment: or 1.2 or 2.0. I give up

Comment: it is announced for 2.1

Comment: This can be misleading, I think it's important to update your answer and mention explicitly that EF versions earlier than EF 7 do support grouping. This answer which is more of a comment than an actual answer to the OP question is misleading when read by itself (and is interpreted as answer to the OP which is not). When reading this, one could get the wrong impression as if even EF 7 don't support grouping and obviously earlier versions don't support it which is just not true.

Comment: It was implemented in ef core 2. But I had problem with includes if I used other GroupBy than .GroupBy(x => x.OfferId, (key, list) =>....).

Answer (score 19):

A useful extension is to collect the results in a `Dictionary` for fast lookup (e.g. in a loop):

```
var resultDict = _dbContext.Projects
    .Where(p => p.Status == ProjectStatus.Active)
    .GroupBy(f => f.Country)
    .Select(g => new { country = g.Key, count = g.Count() })
    .ToDictionary(k => k.country, i => i.count);
```

Originally found here: 
http://www.snippetsource.net/Snippet/140/groupby-and-count-with-ef-in-c

Answer (score 10):

Here are simple examples of group-by in .NET Core 2.1:

```
var query = this.DbContext.Notifications
            .Where(n => n.Sent == false)
            .GroupBy(n => new { n.AppUserId })
            .Select(g => new { AppUserId = g.Key, Count =  g.Count() });

var query2 = from n in this.DbContext.Notifications
            where n.Sent == false
            group n by n.AppUserId into g
            select new { id = g.Key,  Count = g.Count()};
```

Both of these translate to:

```
SELECT [n].[AppUserId], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [Notifications] AS [n]
WHERE [n].[Sent] = 0
GROUP BY [n].[AppUserId]
```

Comment: How to access this fields ? in var query ?

Answer (score 2):

with EF 6.2 it worked for me

```
  var query = context.People
               .GroupBy(p => new {p.name})
               .Select(g => new { name = g.Key.name, count = g.Count() });
```