# Concatenate and group multiple rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, grouping, group-concat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to retrieve two columns data in A,B format in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145379/how-to-retrieve-two-columns-data-in-a-b-format-in-oracle)

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
NAME          GROUP_NAME
name1         groupA
name2         groupB
name5         groupC
name4         groupA
name3         groupC
```

I'd like to have a result like this:

```
GROUP_NAME     NAMES
groupA         name1,name4
groupB         name2
groupC         name3,name5
```

If there were only one column in the table, I could concatenate the records by doing the following, but with grouping in the context, I really don't have much idea.

Concatatenating one column table:

```
SELECT names 
FROM (SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(names,' ') names, level
      FROM name_table

      START WITH names = (SELECT names FROM name_table WHERE rownum = 1)
      CONNECT BY PRIOR names < names
      ORDER BY level DESC)
      WHERE rownum = 1
```

### Updated:

I now have a solution by using `LISTAGG`:

```
SELECT
group_name,
LISTAGG(name, ', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY GROUP) "names"
FROM name_table
GROUP BY group_name
```

Still interested in a more "general" solution for cases when `LISTAGG` is not available.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  The options available depend on the Oracle version.

Comment: If you want to use something common, you should write own aggregate  function
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/aggr_functions.htm can help

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Consider using [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) function in case you're on 11g:

```
select grp, listagg(name,',') within group( order by name ) 
  from name_table group by grp
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13401/15)

**upd:** In case you're not, consider using analytics:

```
select grp,
    ltrim(max(sys_connect_by_path
       (name, ',' )), ',')
        scbp
  from (select name, grp,
            row_number() over
           (partition by grp
            order by name) rn
         from tab
          )
start with rn = 1
connect by prior rn = rn-1
and prior grp = grp
  group by grp
  order by grp
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/13401/20)

Comment: Thank you sir! I wasn't aware of LISTAGG at all. Gave it a quick try and it gave me what I wanted!