# How to maintain order with distinct or group by in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, distinct

I have couple of columns in the table in Oracle DB, one is of varchar2 type while other is of date. I want to retrieve distinct ordered data

The following is the output of the below query

```
select CS_ID,CS_Date from CSM order by CS_Date;
```

which yields:

```
CS_ID                    CS_Date
CS0000000001    29/03/15 14:23:25.872000000
CS0000000001    29/03/15 14:23:30.546000000
CS0000000001    29/03/15 14:23:30.577000000
CS0000000001    29/03/15 14:24:54.331000000
CS0000000001    29/03/15 14:39:51.881000000
CS0000000001    29/03/15 14:44:18.306000000
CS0000000001    29/03/15 14:44:27.372000000
CS0000000002    29/03/15 15:38:40.657000000
CS0000000003    29/03/15 18:41:15.409000000
CS0000000004    29/03/15 19:31:45.614000000
```

After adding distinct, following is the output. Ordered is not maintained after adding distinct

```
select distinct CS_ID from (
    select CS_ID,CS_Date from CSM order by CS_Date 
) v
```

which yields:

```
CS_ID
CS0000000002
CS0000000004
CS0000000003
CS0000000001
```

I am expecting the following output

```
CS_ID
CS0000000001
CS0000000002
CS0000000003
CS0000000004
```

Could you please advise to how to maintain the order with distinct clause?

Comment: Are you trying to order by the `cs_id` or the `cs_date`?  In your example, you would appear to get the results you wanted by simply ignoring the `cs_date` and sorting on the `cs_id`.  If you want to sort by the `cs_date`, do you want to sort by the `min(cs_date)` the `max(cs_date)` or by some other logic?  What happens if one `CS0001` row comes after the first `CS0002` row but before the last `CS0002` row?

Comment: @Jason I want to sort by cs_date, there can be other columns where i have to sort on. But end output should provide distinct CS_ID while retaining the order.

Comment: What order are you trying to retain?  In your example, there are no overlaps so you can ignore the date and just sort on `cs_id`.  My guess is that in your real table, you can have some `CS0001` rows that have a `cs_date` before the first `CS0002` rows and some that have a `cs_date` after the first `CS0002` row.  If that's the case, which `cs_date` do you want to sort by?  The `min(cs_date)`?  The `max(cs_date)`?  Something else?

Comment: if anyone want to `group by + join rows data`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558509/concatenate-and-group-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Answer (score 2):

This will list each `cs_id` in order of the **earliest** `cs_date` for each.

```
select cs_id
from(
select cs_id,
       row_number() over(partition by cs_id order by cs_date) as rn,
       row_number() over(order by cs_date) as rn2
from csm
)
where rn = 1
order by rn2
```

(and, likewise, show each `cs_id` only once, achieving what you want with `distinct`)

Comment: Thanks @BrianDeMilia, its working as expected. I have added one more column to sort and i require this for pagination. So i have modified the query as below and its working ok. Just want to know whether its efficient or there is any other way to do it.

SELECT outer.* FROM (SELECT ROWNUM rnum, Inner.*  FROM(
    (SELECT cs_id FROM (SELECT Cs_Id,
        Row_Number() Over(Partition BY Cs_Id Order By Cs_Date, Staff_Id DESC) AS Rn, row_number() over(order by cs_date, Staff_ID DESC)  AS rn2 FROM csm ) WHERE Rn = 1 ORDER BY rn2
    ) INNER )) Outer Where Outer.Rnum >=2 AND outer.rnum <=10

Comment: @RajaReddy for pagination purposes that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cs_id
from (select cs_id, min(cs_date) as min_cs_date
    from csm
    group by cs_id)
order by min_s_date
```