# sql query for grouping two columns and comma separate value in 3rd column

Tags: sql, oracle

### I have 3 tables
Table A

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |

### Table B

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 2 | y |
| 3 | z |

### Table C

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| x | test1 |
| x | test2 |
| x | test3 |
| y | test4 |
| y | test5 |
| z | test6 |
| z | test7 |

So my requirement is I need to get the result as

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | test1,test2,test3 |
| B | test4,test5 |
| C | test6, test7 |

can some one help, there is relation between the tables. I am using Oracle 19c

Thank you.

Comment: Please fix your formatting and also tell us which _version_ of SQL you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558509/concatenate-and-group-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for :

```
SELECT 
    A.col1,
    LISTAGG(C.col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY C.col2) "col2"
FROM A
JOIN B on A.col2 = B.col1
JOIN C on B.col2 = C.col1
GROUP BY A.col1
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6beedc791ce6bc1ee199f25b90cb1850)