# Getting the first record by date and other field in .net core 3

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the most recent record *by another field* 'group' using .net core 3. In .net core 2 this was possible using GroupBy but this no longer works and causes an exception - and now i am looking for an alternative.

Entity looks as follows:

```
Client --> Messages
```

**Example: The data is as follows in a Messages table:**

```
|Date      |Client |Message |
|01-01-2019|A      |Hello   |
|05-10-2019|A      |Blah    |
|06-11-2019|A      |Newest  |*Most recent by Date for Group A 
|03-01-2019|B      |Oldest  |
|10-05-2019|B      |Test    |
|20-10-2019|B      |Also New|*Most recent by Date for Group B
```

I would like the response to have only:

```
|Date      |Client |Message |
|06-11-2019|A      |Newest  |*Most recent by Date for Group A
|20-10-2019|B      |Also New|*Most recent by Date for Group B
```

Previously i could do the following:

```
PersistenceManager.Context.Client.Include(c => c.Client).Where(x.Date >= date).GroupBy(x => x.ClientId).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

I have read a interesting blog [here](https://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2019/10/entity-framework-core-30-hidden-group-by-capabilities-part-1.html) that suggest doing this by starting with the Client entity however i have a lot of Client records (hundreds) and if there is no record it creates a null. This also does not seem like the right solution under the circumstances.

```
Context.Client.Select(g => g.Messages.OrderBy(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault())
                           .ToList();
```

Anyone solved for this type of problem in .net core 3.

**Note: There are solutions i am aware of that use .AsEnumerable(), but this converts the query to a client side query where you can then filter/group/etc. The solution i am looking for is where the query is run on SQL Server.**

This is the same issue as referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273485/entity-framework-select-one-of-each-group-by-date) but for earlier EF versions.

*Note: Date Column is DD-MM-YYYY.*