# Ef Core 3 .GroupBy() Select one of each group by date

Tags: c#, group-by, ef-core-3.1

Basically I want to do the same thing as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16274992/4138686 , but using this answer in EF Core 3.1.3 gives me

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
>   KeySelector: (r.Price), 
>   ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: 
>       EntityType: RetailerRate
>       ValueBufferExpression: 
>           (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>       IsNullable: False
>   )
>   )
>       .OrderByDescending(r => r.CreatedAt)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Here is the code:

```
await _db.RetailerRates
                .GroupBy(r => r.Price)
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.CreatedAt).First())
                .ToListAsync();
```

Is there a way to retrieve the first element based on a date from every group in EF Core 3.1?

Comment: Have you considered `ToList`ing _before_ the `GroupBy` like the error suggests?

Comment: @mjwills Not really an option because I can have 10k+ rows in RetailerRates. Query should be done in SQL Server

Comment: My app server eats 10k+ rows for breakfast. Did you try it? Was it fast enough? _I am not saying there isn't a better option - just suggesting you give it a try._

Comment: @mjwills I have not tried it. If there isn't an option to query the db for this data, I'll just create an in-memory storage containing the latest rates and with each addition, I'll replace the old one. Will do a better job

Comment: Try to replace .First() by .FirstOrDefault(), .First() usually cannot be translated to SQL

Comment: .FirstOrDefault() was the first thing I tried, because of the answer that I copied from the question I linked. Neither work

Comment: Linked "duplicate" posts show workaround. Associated EF Core issues: [Support ability to select top N of each group #13805](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13805) and [Translate GroupBy followed by FirstOrDefault over group #12088](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12088)