# Can you use grouping in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some SQL code that I want to "convert" to an entity framework 'call'.

This is the code:

```
select  itemStatus, avg(UnitPrice) from ItemSalesHistory
where item = 'BQF09-L-Q007'
group by itemStatus
```

I'm new to using Entity Framework.

Comment: Yes, did you Google this?  "entity framework group by" has lots of results.  Please see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: I did, but I didn't understand any of the results that I found. Why so serious ???

Comment: In the future, show us what you've tried and what you didn't understand in your research.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11564436/10380786), you can apply it to your situation:

```cs
var query = ItemSalesHistory
  .Where(x => x.item == 'BQF09-L-Q007')
  .GroupBy(x => x.itemStatus)
  .Select(g => new { itemStatus = g.Key, avg = g.Average(x => x.UnitPrice) });
```

Comment: Most of the EF code I've written returns a list (using the .ToList() option) that I save to a variable that is defined as a list that has the same "type" as the EF call itself.  Does this call also return a list,  and if so, what type ?  I need to define a variable that will "hold" the results of this call, because this call is part of an if/else statement (both of which contains this EF code, though each call is slightly different) and as a such VS requires I define the variable first.

Comment: Ok. Progress is being made. I realized I can add .ToList to the EF code above. Still need to figure out how to declare the variable that will hold the results.

Comment: The result of this query will be a sequence of objects of anonymous type specified in the `Select`, so each item will have fields `itemStatus` and `avg`.