# How to get sum of fields in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a table like this in SQL Server and a model class in C# with Entity Framework Core:

| id | relatedId | dec1 | dec2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 540000 | 250000 |
| 2 | 1 | 255000 | 200000 |
| 3 | 2 | 100 | 200 |
| 4 | 2 | 500 | 400 |

Now I want get sum of dec1 and dec2 for relatedId 1 and 2 seperatly.
like this:

```
relatedId1 sum dec1 = 7950000 and sum dec2 = 450000
relatedId2 sum dec1 - 600 and dec2 = 600
```

in my C# code.

Thanks

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564311/sql-to-entity-framework-count-group-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `GroupBy`, and `Sum` , like so,

```
var summ = entName.GroupBy(t => t.relatedId)
                           .Select(t => new
                           {
                               relatedId = t.Key,
                               dec1Sum = t.Sum(d => d.dec1),
                               dec2Sum = t.Sum(d => d.dec2),
                           }).ToList();

//print the results
summ.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine($"relatedId {t.relatedId}, sum for dec1 : {t.dec1Sum}, sum for dec2 : {t.dec2Sum}"));
```